# Windows Presentation Foundation Host error on Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin-studio

After enabling the Visual Design on Xamarin Studio, I came across something very annoying: a bug in the IDE is keeping me from using the designer.

When I try to open the .xaml file with the **Windows Presentation Host**, it gives the following error, saying the file could not be found. 
This occurred on both Windows 8.1 and 10. 2015 is the only Visual Studio version installed on my machine.

What may be happening?

*Note: messages are in portuguese. The error message says 'Windows could not find C:\...\Vinicius\etc. Make sure the name is correctly typed and try again. ':*

[image: Opening the file]
[image: Error displayed]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. The file path is being passed with the backslashes escaped which is incorrect. I would report a bug at [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).